# Detecting Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to detect every push message that my device gets, I know its probably a private API and I don't even know if its possible at all but this is for a private app that runs on my phone only. So I really don't need any comments on how Apple is going to reject my app.

I have scoured the internet for this and still haven't found a good/any solution. If someone knows how to do this and could provide me with a code example that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Private API or not - there isn't an API on iOS that enables listening to notifications for all apps, for privacy issues.

Comment: Sorry for coming back on this is it possible to do this via bluetooth? I'm really interested on how all those car accessory's do it

Comment: @JasonGiorgioMeulenhoff That's a special hardware API that allows registered devices to receive *some* notifications - Apple approves the hardware, and it's meant for watches and high-tech glasses and things like that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to do this. Your app can only listen to the notifications that are sent to it once it has registered itself for notifications. It cannot listen to notifications sent to other apps.